# How to create and download a PDF with CakePdf not showing it in browser

Tags: pdf, cakephp

I downloaded and installed CakePdf and it works well. However in documentation are shown only 2 ways to proceed:
 - Render to screen with download optional.
 - Create a file and store it in server

I actually want to generate the pdf with the user's data and download it without saving it in the server, but i dont want the browser loads it and shows it in the screen. The instant download when the pdf is shown in browser is nice, but the users who will use this are not familiar with browsers and will get stuck in the pdf page, ignoring how to get back to the menu.

Any help?

Comment: 1) educate your users. I know that's not always helpful... 2) what's your context? If this were (for an overly specific example) a mod_perl Apache server I'd set it up to create and store to server in a tempspace, then download (etc) and delete - but that's making a TON of assumptions. Please elaborate. :)

Comment: Hi, Paul. Yes, the server is Apache and I can save a temp file for downloading and delete it after that, as I dont want to save all the pdf's created because there will be tons of them. But I dont like those asynchronous methods, i mean: create, save, download and delete; because i must ensure it is saved before downloading and it is downloaded before deleting. I know I can solve that in different ways, but the instant generation and auto download process CakePdf provides is perfect, the only problem is it prints the pdf to screen, which i dont want.

Comment: If you can edit the http headers you can tell the browser to save it, but I'm not familiar with CakePDF so I don't know how much flexibility you have. All I was saying is, worst case, you can emulate the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I use `TCPDF` as my PDF generator, but I assume the method is the same for `CakePdf`. The key here is to generate the PDF as a string variable. Once you have that it's easy to send it both ways.

This will open the PDF inside the browser for viewing:

```
 public function index() {
      $pdf = $this->PdfToString(); // should return PDF as a string
      return $this->response
             ->withType('application/pdf')
             ->withStringBody($pdf);
 }
```

This will make the browser prompt the user to save the PDF:

```
 public function index() {
      $pdf = $this-PdfToString();
      return $this->response
             ->withType('application/pdf')
             ->withStringBody($pdf)
             ->withDownload('document_name.pdf');
 }
```

As you can see it's really easy with CakePHP 3.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what i DONT want. I want the pdf to be downloaded without being printed in the browser and without being prompted for download.

Comment: @Baalhug you can't. It's a security risk to allow a website to download files without a person's permissions. As a developer you should know better.